# cgroup skb egress ebpf hook - skb->cb[0-4] updated values are reset in tc egress ebpf hook

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf

I am just updating the skb->cb with constant values (0xfeed) and trying to get the same packet data at egress tc layer ebpf hook. It is all zero. Am i missing something here?
Is there anyway to send meta data between hooks with skb itself (LRU_HASH map may help but having in-band metadata will be faster, I think).

```
SEC("cgroup/skb")
int cgrp_dump_pkt(struct __sk_buff *skb) {

void *data_end = (void *) (long) skb->data_end;
void *data     = (void *) (long) skb->data;

if(data < data_end)
{   

    skb->cb[0] = 0xfeed;
    skb->cb[1] = 0xfeed;
    skb->cb[2] = 0xfeed;
    skb->cb[3] = 0xfeed;
    skb->cb[4] = 0xfeed;
           bpf_printk("hash:%x  mark:%x pri:%x", skb->hash, skb->mark, skb->priority);
    bpf_printk("cb0:%x cb1:%x cb2:%x", skb->cb[0], skb->cb[1], skb->cb[2]);
    bpf_printk("cb3:%x cb4:%x", skb->cb[3], skb->cb[4]);
}

return 1;
}
```

The above hook is attached to a docker instance cgroup and I am trying to see the same packets by attaching the hook in tc egress (will just print the packet info includes cb[0-4]). cb[0-4] values are shown as 0. Is it an expected behavior? How to pass the metadata between ebpf hook from cgroup skb to tc egress or lower layers?

Answer (score 2):

I've only ever used the `cb` fields to pass data across BPF tail calls. To pass data from one hook point to another in the stack, you could use `skb->mark` (32-bit value).

Do make sure that no other software is using the same bits you want to use though. See https://github.com/fwmark/registry for example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very quick response. mark and priority are also reset to 0 (i mean, i am not able to use mark field ).

Comment: Do you know what resets the mark? You can check iptables rules, xfrm policies if using IPsec, and `bpftool net` if you suspect there are other BPF programs installed.

Comment: It is new Ubuntu VM and i dont have any rules and i am not using ipsec and i dont have any other program other than the 2 mentioned in the thread. Thank you so much for the very quick reply.